# Magento2 exam certification course doubts

Tags: magento2, certification

Magento2 I was checking/preparing regarding Adobe Certified Professional - Adobe Commerce Developer (AD0-E711).

- Just wanted to know if anyone can help me with the following points that can be covered in this topic

**Describe front-end usage of customer data & Describe cart components**

- It would be really great if someone can guide me on what needs to be study on this topic, I am not able to understand properly on this.

https://express.adobe.com/page/WBhc2rZlIxtWC/

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be something related to Private Content and Sections.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

XS